# Nest.js cant resolve dependencies, can't find my mistake

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm doing a Nest.js program but I can't find my dependencies problem. I have searched quite a lot and I have found a lot of answers regarding this problem, but I can't figure out why my code isn´t working. So I have a product module which has his DTO´s, Entity, Controller, Service and module, besides it has an interface for its service.

**ProductController**

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductServiceInterface } from './interface/product.service.interface'

@Controller('products')
export class ProductController {
  constructor(private readonly productService: ProductServiceInterface) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.productService.test();
  }
}
```

**ProductServiceInterface**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  CreateProductInput,
  CreateProductOutput,
} from '../dto/create-product.dto';
import { FindProductOutput } from '../dto/find-product.dto';

export interface ProductServiceInterface {
  create(input: CreateProductInput): Promise<CreateProductOutput>;
  findProduct(productId: string): Promise<FindProductOutput>;
  test();
}
```

**ProductService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductServiceInterface } from './interface/product.service.interface';
import {
  CreateProductInput,
  CreateProductOutput,
} from './dto/create-product.dto';
import { Product } from './entity/product.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { FindProductOutput } from './dto/find-product.dto';
//import WooCommerce from '../../config/woocomerce.config';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService implements ProductServiceInterface {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Product)
    private productRepository: Repository<Product>,
  ) {}

  public async create(
    productDto: CreateProductInput,
  ): Promise<CreateProductOutput> {
    const product = new Product();
    product.name = productDto.name;
    product.price = productDto.price;
    product.imgUrl = productDto.imgUrl;

    const savedProduct = await this.productRepository.save(product);
    const productOutput = new CreateProductOutput();
    productOutput.id = savedProduct.id;
    return productOutput;
  }

  public async findProduct(idProduct: string): Promise<FindProductOutput> {
    const fetchedProduct = await this.productRepository.findOne(idProduct);
    const productOutput = new FindProductOutput();
    productOutput.id = fetchedProduct.id;
    productOutput.imgUrl = fetchedProduct.imgUrl;
    productOutput.name = fetchedProduct.name;
    productOutput.price = fetchedProduct.price;
    return productOutput;
  }

  public test() {
    return 'test'
    // WooCommerce.get('products', {
    //   pero_page: 20,
    // }).then((resp) => {
    //   return resp;
    // });
  }
}
```

**ProductModule**

```
import { ProductController } from './product.controller';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { Product } from './entity/product.entity';

import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Product])],
  controllers: [ProductController],
  providers: [ProductService],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

**AppModule**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import configuration from 'src/config/configuration';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TypeOrmConfigService } from 'src/config/typeorm.config.service';
import { ProductModule } from './modules/product/product.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: TypeOrmConfigService,
    }),
    ProductModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I hope this code is enough for knowing where my mistake is, I don't like letting others just resolve this for me but I've been watching my code for hours and can't know how to resolve this dependencies problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces disappear at runtime and becomes `{}` or `Object`. Nest uses the parameter type metadata to determine what is supposed to be injected (usually via `ClassType.name`). You have two options to solve this

1. Use an abstract class instead of an interface. This makes the class still visible at runtime so `ClassType.name` still works.
2. Use `@Inject('CustomToken')` as the way to set the metadata for what Nest needs to inject. You then need to make sure register the custom provider using something like

```js
{
  provide: 'CustomToken',
  useClass: ClassToBeUsed
}
```

Either of these methods should fix your issue.